# Jmonkey NullPointerException

Tags: java, animation, nullpointerexception, blender, jmonkeyengine

This is my code to load a node with a model then attach an animation control.  I get a NullPointerException because it is saying my AnimControl is null.

My anim control class is in Models/stickman.blend/Armature/Cube

```
Node model = (Node)assetManager.loadModel("Models/stickman.j3o");
control = model.getControl(AnimControl.class);
control.addListener(this);
channel = control.createChannel();
channel.setAnim("jump");
model.scale(0.25f);
model.addControl(physicsCharacter);
getPhysicsSpace().add(physicsCharacter);
rootNode.attachChild(model);
```

How do I get rid of this nullpointerexception or move the AnimControl class up out of the sub directory so it won't be null? Thanks.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mygame.Main.simpleInitApp(Main.java:96)
at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:226)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

[image]

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the NPE.

Comment: Does that edit help?

Comment: Which line is Main.java:96?

Comment: control.addListener(this);

Comment: Check out the edit. I added a picture of where my AnimControl class is located within the model

Comment: Pretty obvious that `control` is null. What is the definition for `AnimControl`?

Comment: From looking at the tutorials, there is one thing in particular you are not doing. [The tutorials](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php?id=jme3:beginner:hello_animation) for animated models all have something like `rootNode.attachChild(player);` right after the model is loaded but right before they try and get a reference to the models `AnimControl`. I wonder if adding `rootNode.attachChild(model);` right before you try and assign `control` would fix the problem. If Not i would say something is wrong with the model's animation and so it is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullPointerException is telling you as clearly as it can that the variable `control` is null.  This in turn means that `model.getControl(AnimControl.class);` has returned null.  The [javadoc tells you it will do this](http://javadoc.jmonkeyengine.org/com/jme3/scene/Spatial.html#getControl(java.lang.Class)) if there is no control of type AnimControl.class

I think, looking at [the tutorial](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php?id=jme3), that you must attach your Node to the rootNode.  From [this page](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php?id=jme3:beginner:hello_node)

> Every JME3 application has a rootNode: Your game automatically inherits the rootNode object from SimpleApplication.

So, as long as your class `extends SimpleApplication` you just need to add

```
rootNode.attachChild(model);
```

immediately after

```
Node model = (Node)assetManager.loadModel("Models/stickman.j3o");
```

It seems that this attachment will automatically associate your model with a control - as demonstrated in this snippet from the [animation beginners tutorial](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php?id=jme3:beginner:hello_animation)

```
player = (Node) assetManager.loadModel("Models/Oto/Oto.mesh.xml");
player.setLocalScale(0.5f);
rootNode.attachChild(player);
control = player.getControl(AnimControl.class);
```